# Get DOM element's actual width using jsdom

Tags: node.js, jsdom

I wonder if I could get a DOM element's actual width and coordinates, as I can get using .clientWidth / .offsetWidth from within the browser.

Does jsdom has browser rendering capabilities in order to get this data?

If not, how can I get this within node.js server?

Thanks!

Comment: This has nothing to do with node.js.  Node.js executes on an application / web server, not the client's browser.  I think jQuery has functions to get you the computed width and height of an element.

Comment: @Brandon: node has many libraries that emulate the DOM API on the server; jsdom is one of them.

Comment: Brandon, can you write some of them? This is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

JSDOM is strictly a DOM API emulation library.  It does not attempt to actually render a document, which is necessary to compute element size and position.

You may want to look at [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).  It is a full WebKit renderer with a JavaScript API.  It is entirely separate from node, so you either need to write a utility script using Phantom's API, or use [a npm module that lets you control Phantom from node](https://npmjs.org/package/phantom-proxy).

Comment: I'm aware of this unreliable integration between them. I'm looking for official solutions. If it's not possible, I will mark this as an answer.