# How to mock react custom hook returned value?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library

Here is my custom hook:

```
  export function useClientRect() {
    const [scrollH, setScrollH] = useState(0);
    const [clientH, setClientH] = useState(0);
    const ref = useCallback(node => {
      if (node !== null) {
        setScrollH(node.scrollHeight);
        setClientH(node.clientHeight);
      }
    }, []);
    return [scrollH, clientH, ref];
  }
}
```

I want each time that it is called, it return my values. like:

```
jest.mock('useClientRect', () => [300, 200, () => {}]);
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you take a look at the Jest docs? https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-user-modules

Comment: @Timo looked... no luck. I think I may need to first spy on useClientRect then mock the return.

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/testing-library/react-hooks-testing-library?

Comment: what if you mock `scrollHeight`/`clientHeight` instead of mocking hook? https://stackoverflow.com/a/56457850/2071697

Answer (score 222):

Load the hook as a module. Then mock the module:

```js
jest.mock('module_path/module_name', () => ({
    useClientRect: () => [300, 200, jest.fn()]
}));
```

mock should be called on top of the file outside test fn. Therefore we are going to have only one array as the mocked value.

If you want to mock the hook with different values in different tests:

```js
import * as hooks from 'module_path/module_name';

it('a test', () => {
    jest.spyOn(hooks, 'useClientRect').mockImplementation(() => ([100, 200, jest.fn()]));
    //rest of the test
});
```

Comment: mother of god, pointing out that it needed to be at the top was helpful - somehow no one has mentioned this in the dozen other tutorials i've looked at

Comment: For me it gives the error that "useClientRect is  not a function undefined given instead"

Comment: @MuhammadHaseeb You need to replace useClientRect with the name of your hook. In this example the hook returns an array that needs to be mocked.

Comment: @Homa yeah I put my hook name but my hook returns and object

Comment: @muhammad-haseeb you need to replace the array with a mocked object. In your code console.log the value that your hook is returning and replace the array like: `jest.spyOn(hooks, 'useYourHookName').mockImplementation(() => ({a: 100, b: 200, c: jest.fn()}));`.

Comment: What should be the `module_name`?

Comment: @Mohammad Kermani when you have a hook file, it cab be something like  '../folder_name/hook_file_name.ts'. when you mock a hook from a npm library it will be the name of the npm library.

Comment: In my particular case, I had to do `import hooks from 'module_name` instead of `import * as hooks from 'module_name'`. With the latter, the top-level mock was called, but the spy was not.

Comment: full file code would be much helpful.

Comment: I facing issues when the custom hook is default exported. How do I spy on it's returned values in different scenarios?

Comment: Does this work if you are passing an argument with the hook?

Answer (score 60):

Adding on to this answer for typescript users encountering the `TS2339: Property 'mockReturnValue' does not exist on type` error message. There is now a [jest.mocked](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#jestmockedsource-options) helper you can call to mock with Type defs (which is a port of the ts-jest/utils `mocked` function).

```
import useClientRect from './path/to/useClientRect';

jest.mock('./path/to/useClientRect');

const mockUseClientRect = jest.mocked(useClientRect);

describe("useClientRect", () => {
  it("mocks the hook's return value", () => {
    mockUseClientRect.mockReturnValue([300, 200, () => {}]);
    // ... do stuff
  });

  it("mocks the hook's implementation", () => {
    mockUseClientRect.mockImplementation(() => [300, 200, () => {}]);
    // ... do stuff
  });
});
```

Comment: especially for Typescript usage this provides the best answer! thanks

Answer (score 17):

Well, this is quite tricky and sometimes developers get confused by the library but once you get used to it, it becomes a piece of cake. I faced a similar issue a few hours back and I'm sharing my solution for you to derive your solution easily.

My custom Hook:

```
  import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
  import { getFileData } from "../../API/gistsAPIs";
    
  export const useFilesData = (fileUrl: string) => {
    const [fileData, setFileData] = useState<string>("");
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState<boolean>(false);
    useEffect(() => {
      setLoading(true);
      getFileData(fileUrl).then((fileContent) => {
        setFileData(fileContent);
        setLoading(false);
      });
    }, [fileUrl]);
    
    return { fileData, loading };
  };
```

My mock code:
Please include this mock in the test file outside of your test function.
Note: Be careful about the return object of mock, it should match with the expected response.

```
const mockResponse = {
  fileData: "This is a mocked file",
  loading: false,
};
jest.mock("../fileView", () => {
  return {
    useFilesData: () => {
      return {
        fileData: "This is a mocked file",
        loading: false,
      };
    },
  };
});
```

The complete test file would be:

```
import { render, screen, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect";
import FileViewer from "../FileViewer";

const mockResponse = {
  fileData: "This is a mocked file",
  loading: false,
};
jest.mock("../fileView", () => {
  return {
    useFilesData: () => {
      return {
        fileData: "This is a mocked file",
        loading: false,
      };
    },
  };
});

describe("File Viewer", () => {
  it("display the file heading", async () => {
    render(<FileViewer fileUrl="" filename="regex-tutorial.md" className="" />);
    const paragraphEl = await screen.findByRole("fileHeadingDiplay");
    expect(paragraphEl).toHaveTextContent("regex-tutorial.md");
  });
}
```

Comment: How would you share the mock between tests? Any idea?

Comment: What is the point of mockResponse variable? You don't use it anywhere?

Comment: This has really helped me. Thanks a million

Answer (score 1):

In my case I resolved it doing this:

```
jest.mock('pathToTheHookFile/useClientRect');

describe('It tests the hook', ()=> {
  beforeEach(() => {
    useClientRect.mockReturnValue([300, 200, jest.fn()])
  });

  it('Tests something', ()=> {
    ...
  }
});
```