# Can't mock useAsync with react test library

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-hooks, react-testing-library, react-hooks-testing-library

I am attempting to test a component that uses the **useAsync** hook using the **@testing-library/react** .

If I use jest.mock on the TestAPI module, followed by getTest.mockResolvedValueOnce(testArray); on the getTest function then I would expect the mock to correctly return the test values.

Test :

```
import React from "react";
import { render, screen, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import TestPanel from "./TestPanel";
import { getTest } from "./TestAPI";

jest.mock("./TestAPI");

it("renders cards correctly", async () => {
  const testArray = ["hi there"];
  getTest.mockResolvedValueOnce(testArray);

  render(<TestPanel />);

  expect(getTest).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(getTest).toHaveBeenCalledWith();

  await waitFor(() => expect(screen.getByText("hi there")).toBeInTheDocument());
});
```

Component to be tested :

```
import React from "react";
import { useAsync } from "react-async-hook";
import { getTest } from "./TestAPI";

export default function TestPanel() {
  const { result: elems } = useAsync(getTest, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {elems &&
        elems.map((elem) => {
          return <div>{elem}</div>;
        })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

API call :

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export async function getTest(): Promise {
  const response = await axios.get("/someservice");

  return response.data || [];
}
```

However if I run the test then an exception is thrown saying that the "elems.map" is undefined.

On closer inspection it seems that the elems is a promise.

[image]

Is there something that I am doing wrong?

Comment: Instead of mocking the hook, why don't you just test it using [react-hooks-testing-library](https://github.com/testing-library/react-hooks-testing-library)? You can render the hook `const {result: hookResult, waitFor} = renderHook(() => useAsync(getTest, []));` and then wait for the result to be non-null: `await waitFor(() => hookResult.result);` and then write expect cases: `expect(getTest).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are your issues: [*react-async-hook*](https://github.com/slorber/react-async-hook/issues/24) & [*jest*](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/6645)

[Here](https://github.com/slorber/react-async-hook/blob/dddfc1c1b97ff8736b9237c50e2b35610c62ed75/src/index.ts#L249) `react-async-hook` uses `instanceof Promise` but `Jest.mockResolvedValueOnce` returns not a real JS `Promise`, but a promise-like object. So the `useAsync()` treats the mock as a sycn function.

The solution is to use `mockImplementationOnce` instead of `mockResolvedValueOnce`

```js
getTest.mockImplementation(async () => testArray)
```

From the [docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-function-api#mockfnmockresolvedvalueoncevalue):

> **mockFn.mockResolvedValueOnce(value)**
>
> Syntactic sugar function for:
>
> ```js
> jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(value));
> ```

But, sadly, it's not just a syntactic sugar.

Comment: ok thanks . replacing that line with your line seems to make it work for me now. Still not exactly sure why, it still hurts my brain a bit. Will read up on the links you posted. thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

i think you should mock your return from the useAsync hook itself.

```js
jest.mock("path/to/useAsync", () => ({
  result: ["test"]
}));`
```

Comment: I tried this : jest.mock("react-async-hook/useAsync", () => ({result: ["test"],})); . Is that what you meant? It doesnt seem to work

Comment: yes that's idea but try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60282832/12219726) and make sure to mock on top