# How to mock useRef using jest.mock and react testing library

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library

I have a test case where I need to mock useRef inorder to return a mock current value. I tried jest.mock but it returns an HTMLDivElement instead.

code:

```
   const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);
```

test:

```
  jest.mock('react', () => {
     const originReact = jest.requireActual('react');
       return {
          ...originReact,
          useRef: jest.fn(),
       };
  });



  React.useRef.mockReturnValue({ current: {offsetWith: 100} });
```

Mock returns

```
[ { type: 'return', value: { current: [HTMLDivElement] } } ]
```

Comment: Don't mock *any* of React's API, you don't own that. Test the *behaviour* of the component, not the *implementation*.

Comment: i see. is there a way to test if the current ref value like offsetWidth changes. thanks

Answer (score 7):

@jonrsharpe's suggestion is the general principle of component testing, but your question is a special case, involving some properties and methods of the DOM, such as `offsetWidth` and `getBoundingClientRect()` methods. The runtime environment of `jsdom` cannot return and the rendering engine under the browser runtime environment The returned result causes the `offsetWidth` and the property values returned by the `getBoundingClientRect()` method to always be `0`.

So here we need mock `ref`.

The mock `ref` here is also special. In addition to using `jest.mock()` for partial mocking, the `ref.current` property will be assigned by `react` after the component is mounted. In order to intercept this operation, we need to create a mock `ref` object with a `current` object property, use the `Object.defineProperty()` method to define `getter` and `setter` for this `ref.current` property, and intercept property assignment.

`jest.spyOn` method takes an optional third argument of accessType that can be either 'get' or 'set', which proves to be useful when you want to spy on a getter or a setter, respectively.

E.g.

`index.tsx`:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

export default function App() {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(ref.current?.offsetWidth);
  }, [ref]);
  return <div ref={ref}>app</div>;
}
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils';
import App from './';

jest.mock('react', () => {
  return {
    ...jest.requireActual<typeof React>('react'),
    useRef: jest.fn(),
  };
});

const useMockRef = mocked(useRef);

describe('66332902', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });
  test('should mock ref and offsetWidth', () => {
    const ref = { current: {} };
    Object.defineProperty(ref, 'current', {
      set(_current) {
        if (_current) {
          jest.spyOn(_current, 'offsetWidth', 'get').mockReturnValueOnce(100);
        }
        this._current = _current;
      },
      get() {
        return this._current;
      },
    });
    useMockRef.mockReturnValueOnce(ref);
    render(<App />);
  });
});
```

test result: (*see the logs*)

```
 PASS  examples/66332902/index.test.tsx (9.518 s)
  66332902
    ✓ should mock ref and offsetWidth (39 ms)

  console.log
    100

      at examples/66332902/index.tsx:6:13

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        10.106 s
```

Comment: This does not work, if inside `<App>` other components call useRef. Any idea how to solve this @slideshowp2?

Comment: @philk - i'm also searching for a way to mock ref properties for a given component... not the entire useRef hook!

Comment: please have a look at this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73972445/forwardref-component-error-jest-react-native