# How to test scrollHeight, scrollWidth, clientHeight and clientWidth with react-testing-library and jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-testing

I just can't figure out, how I'm supposed to mock / get data from `scrollHeight`, `scrollWidth`, `clientHeight` and `clientWidth` in test.

For better introduction, my task is to detect whether `table` element is scrollable or not and if it is, then I have to add `tabIndex` attribute to it's wrapper.

In my component, I'm simply attaching `ref` to `div`, in which is `table` element.

```
const tableWrapperRef = useRef(null);

<div ref="tableWrapperRef">
  <table>
    //table content
  </table>
</div>
```

Then in `useEffect` I'm getting `tableWrapperRef.current` and searching for `table` element in it. Next, I will simply pick these values and I compare them to each other in `isScrollable` function. Result from this function is the key for me, because depending on that result I'm adding `tabIndex` attribute to `div`.

```
  function isScrollable(
    tableWrapper,
    tableElement
  ) {
    if (
      tableElement.scrollWidth > tableWrapper.clientWidth ||
      tableElement.scrollHeight > tableWrapper.clientHeight
    ) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (tableWrapperRef.current) {
      const tableWrapper = tableWrapperRef.current;
      const tableElement = tableWrapperRef.current?.querySelector("table");

      if (isScrollable(tableWrapper, tableElement!)) {
        return tableWrapper.setAttribute("tabIndex", "0");
      }
    }
  }, [tableWrapperRef.current]);
```

It is working as it should, but I can't figure it out how to test it. Test always fails, because `scrollWidth`, `scrollHeight`, `clientWidth` and `clientHeight` values are always `0`. I figured out that it's because `jsdom` doesn't have access to these values.

**My test**

In my test, to simulate smaller window and to force table to shrink and scroll I'm using `resizeWindow` function.

```
function resizeWindow(x: number, y: number) {
  // @ts-ignore
  window.innerWidth = x;
  // @ts-ignore
  window.innerHeight = y;
  window.dispatchEvent(new Event("resize"));
}

test.each([[175, 300]])("default render (%p x %p)", async (x, y) => {
  resizeWindow(x, y);

  render(
    <Table
      columns={columns}
      data={data}
      caption="Názov tabuľky"
      className="test-className"
      data-testid="table"
    />
  );

  const tableWrapper = await screen.getByTestId("table");

  expect(tableWrapper).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(tableWrapper.getAttribute("tabIndex")).toBe("0");
});
```

I've also found [this question here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47823616/mocking-clientheight-and-scrollheight-in-react-enzyme-for-test/56457850#56457850), with [reference on official jest docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname-accesstype), but I just don't understand how to use it in this case.. Can someone please help me with this?