# Test a react hook which receives an HTMLElement with jest

Tags: html, typescript, testing, react-hooks, mocking

I have this custom hook:

```
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

...

const isScrollerAtBottom = (elt: HTMLElement) => {
    return (
        Math.floor(Number(elt?.scrollHeight) - Number(elt?.scrollTop)) >
        Number(elt?.clientHeight)
    );
};

export function useScroll(container: HTMLElement): useScrollProps {
    console.dir(container, {depth: 12});
    
    const [displayScroller, setDisplayScroller] = useState(true);
    const [scrollerTop, setScrollerTop] = useState(0);
    const [scrollerLeft, setScrollerLeft] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        const containerDimensions = container
            ? container.getBoundingClientRect()
            : null;
        console.dir(containerDimensions, {depth: 12});

        const left =
            (containerDimensions?.x || 0) +
            (containerDimensions?.width || 0) -
            40;
        const top = containerDimensions?.height || 0;
        setScrollerTop(top);
        setScrollerLeft(left);

        setDisplayScroller(isScrollerAtBottom(container));
    });

    ...

    const handleScroll = (event: React.UIEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
        const elt = event.target as HTMLElement;
        setDisplayScroller(isScrollerAtBottom(elt));
    };

    return {
        displayScroller,
        scrollerTop,
        scrollerLeft,
        handleScroll,
    };
}
```

And I'd like to test it. My problem is how to mock the HTMLElement as container.

I tried this:

```
import { JSXElement } from "@babel/types";
import React from 'react';
import { render, renderHook, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { useScroll, useScrollProps } from "../../hooks/useScroll";

describe("useScroll", () => {
  const container: HTMLElement = document.createElement("div");
  container.style.width = "300px";
  container.style.height = "800px";
  container.style.display = "block";
  const content: HTMLElement = document.createElement("p");
  content.innerHTML = `... ... ...`;
  container.appendChild(content);

  test("should return scroller position and display flag", () => {
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useScroll(container));
    console.log(result.current);
  });
});
```

But the container dimension is not get in the customHook:

```
 console.dir                                                                                          
    {                                                                                                  
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      bottom: 0,
      height: 0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
      top: 0,
      width: 0
    }
```

If I can get the right dimension of the container mock then I think I can continue to proceed to do some assertions, but I don't know how to get there.

Any idea will be appreciated.
Thanks!

**POST-EDIT:**
What I have seen so far about similar needs is people use to mock such function (`getBoundingClientRect`), but if I can't use a mocked HTML element and have the expected calculations for the mocked HTMLElement using the hook I don't think the test will make sense. **What I want to test is it returns true/false if the scroll is at the bottom of the container.**
Any ideas, comments and/or opinions about this are welcome.

**TRY: Render component**

```js
    import { fireEvent, render, renderHook } from "@testing-library/react";
    import { useScroll } from "../../hooks/useScroll";
    
    describe("useScroll", () => {
      test("should return scroller position and display flag", () => {
        const { container } = render(
          <div style={{ width: "200px", height: "700px" }}></div>
        );
        const { result } = renderHook(() => useScroll(container));
    
        container.addEventListener("scroll", result.current.handleScroll);
    
        fireEvent.scroll(container, { target: { scrollTop: 0 } });
        expect(result.current.displayScroller).toBeFalsy();
    
        fireEvent.scroll(container, { target: { scrollTop: 700 } });
        expect(result.current.displayScroller).toBeTruthy();
      });
    });
```

But the last assertion `expect(result.current.displayScroller).toBeTruthy();` is still false although the event returned in the hook I am testing is trigered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I finally have done is the following test:

```js
describe("useScroll", () => {

  const scrollHeight = 2392;
  const clientHeight = 767;
  const scrollTop = scrollHeight - clientHeight;
  
  test("should return displayScroller false if the scroll is at the bottom", () => {
    const { container } = render(<div></div>);

    jest.spyOn(container, "scrollHeight", "get").mockImplementation(() => scrollHeight);
    jest.spyOn(container, "clientHeight", "get").mockImplementation(() => clientHeight);

    const { result } = renderHook(() => useScroll(container));

    container.addEventListener("scroll", result.current.handleScroll);

    fireEvent.scroll(container, { target: { scrollTop } });
    expect(result.current.displayScroller).toBeFalsy();
  });

  test("should return displayScroller true if the scroll is not at the bottom", () => {
    const { container } = render(<div></div>);

    jest.spyOn(container, "scrollHeight", "get").mockImplementation(() => scrollHeight);
    jest.spyOn(container, "clientHeight", "get").mockImplementation(() => clientHeight);

    const { result } = renderHook(() => useScroll(container));

    container.addEventListener("scroll", result.current.handleScroll);

    for (let i = 0; i < scrollTop; i++) {
      fireEvent.scroll(container, { target: { scrollTop: i } });
      expect(result.current.displayScroller).toBeTruthy();
    }
  });
});
```

what it is testing the hook behavieur of scrolling and returning the correspondant value to display or not display the scroll.

Thanks everyone here to contribute on this.

References:

[Mocking clientHeight and scrollHeight in React + Enzyme for test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47823616/mocking-clientheight-and-scrollheight-in-react-enzyme-for-test)

---

One of the components where I use the custom hook:

```js
import ... 
...
import { useScroll } from "../../../hooks/useScroll";
...
import { Contents } from "./Contents";

export interface IndiceProps {
  publications: Publication[];
  isHamburguer?: boolean;
}

export function MenuIndex({ publications, isHamburguer=false }: IndiceProps) {
  ...
  const containerRef = useRef<HTMLUListElement>(null);
  const { displayScroller, scrollerTop, scrollerLeft, handleScroll } =
    useScroll(containerRef.current as HTMLUListElement);

    ...

  return (
    <>
      <Box
        className={`
          ${publicationStyles.hideScrollBar}
          ${isHamburguer 
              ? publicationStyles.hamburguerContainer 
              : publicationStyles.container}
        `}
        onScroll={handleScroll}
        ref={containerRef}
      >
        <Contents
          publications={publications}
          displayScroller={displayScroller}
          scrollerLeft={scrollerLeft}
        />
      </Box>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: What is result.current.handleScroll? Is this function exposed only for the test?

Comment: No, it is the handler I inject in the component I use this scrolling feature. I edit the answer with the code where I am using it. I use it in other components too.

Answer (score 1):

The testing library is more about the expected result rather than the procedure.

Can you create a component inside the test, mount your hook, do whatever you need, and check if the scroll happened?

Or maybe this can help you.
https://github.com/testing-library/react-testing-library/issues/671

Comment: I edit the question with what I am trying now, but it still doesn't work as I expect. The post seems to advice to do E2E tests for this sort of things, but I, if I understood correctly, I believe it might be a way. What I tried looks like promising but not :/

Comment: I can't see a reason why this hook could not be tested on its own.

Comment: Of course, there could be a test, which uses it in a component as well, but just purely as a unit test, the hook can be tested as well.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `@testing-library/react` library will give you usable values for position, size or scroll state. You could use a framework which runs the test in a real browser, there you could get it (e.g. `Cypress`). However, this is more complicated. I would advise you just to use a simpler solution:

```js
import { JSXElement } from "@babel/types";
import React from 'react';
import { render, renderHook, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import { useScroll, useScrollProps } from "../../hooks/useScroll";

describe("useScroll", () => {
  test("should return scroller position and display flag", () => {
    const container = {
      getBoundingClientRect: jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ x: 0, y: 10, width: 100, height: 300 }),
      scrollHeight: 50,
      scrollTop: 20,
      clientHeight: 300,
    } as unknown as HTMLElement;
    const { result } = renderHook(() => useScroll(container));
    expect(result.current).toEqual({ ... });
  });
});
```

I used `as unknown as HTMLElement` to silence Typescript errors (it might work without it too, just try `as HTMLElement`). Creating such shallow object works for us, since we're using only a few properties from the `HTMLElement`. It's easier to get it work like this, rather than trying to "hack" the original `HTMLElement`. For testing this is fine, but it's not suitable for "real" code running in the browser.

Also note, I used `jest.fn().mockReturnValue({ x: 0, y: 10, width: 100, height: 300})` for `getBoundingClientRect`, which makes it easy to verify that the function was actually called, e.g.:

```js
expect(container.getBoundingClientRect).toHaveBeenCalledWith();
```

Additionally, your `container: HTMLElement` argument in the `useScroll` function is not allowing falsy values, so it'll never be `null`:

```js
  const containerDimensions = container
    ? container.getBoundingClientRect()
    : null;
```

You could use `HTMLElement | null` as the argument's type or just simply drop the ternary operator.

Comment: I am not looking for to test if getBoundingClientRect is called or not, please check my answer, I think I have what I was looking for. Please add a comment over my own answer if you'd like to provide a feedback. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. It’s optional to verify the call of getBoundingClientRect. I added it as an additional tip. The gist of this answer is to create a simple object with the required properties as the container.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think I see the problem as to why Jest may not be picking up your test React Hook properly

When you use `document.createElement("div")` it isn't `HTMLElement` being returned as the type but rather an `HTMLDivElement`. Likewise, when you use `document.createElement("p")` it is `HTMLParagraphElement` not `HTMLElement` being returned as the type. `HTMLElement` is the base Entity that all other `JSX.IntrinsicElement` types extend in their interface definitions. You can see this for yourself by plugging the code I've included below into a `.ts` file

```
export type DocumentCreateElementTagNameTandem = {[P in keyof globalThis.HTMLElementTagNameMap]: globalThis.HTMLElementTagNameMap[P]}
```

I went ahead and set up a dummy function to get intellisense to infer its return type for me, which is included below

```
    export type DocumentCreateElementTagNameTandem = {
      [P in keyof globalThis.HTMLElementTagNameMap]: globalThis.HTMLElementTagNameMap[P];
    };

    export const testingDocumentCreateElementTagNameTandem = (
      props: DocumentCreateElementTagNameTandem 
    ): {
      a: HTMLAnchorElement;
      abbr: HTMLElement;
      address: HTMLElement;
      area: HTMLAreaElement;
      article: HTMLElement;
      aside: HTMLElement;
      audio: HTMLAudioElement;
      b: HTMLElement;
      base: HTMLBaseElement;
      bdi: HTMLElement;
      bdo: HTMLElement;
      blockquote: HTMLQuoteElement;
      body: HTMLBodyElement;
      br: HTMLBRElement;
      button: HTMLButtonElement;
      canvas: HTMLCanvasElement;
      caption: HTMLTableCaptionElement;
      cite: HTMLElement;
      code: HTMLElement;
      col: HTMLTableColElement;
      colgroup: HTMLTableColElement;
      data: HTMLDataElement;
      datalist: HTMLDataListElement;
      dd: HTMLElement;
      del: HTMLModElement;
      details: HTMLDetailsElement;
      dfn: HTMLElement;
      dialog: HTMLDialogElement;
      div: HTMLDivElement;
      dl: HTMLDListElement;
      dt: HTMLElement;
      em: HTMLElement;
      embed: HTMLEmbedElement;
      fieldset: HTMLFieldSetElement;
      figcaption: HTMLElement;
      figure: HTMLElement;
      footer: HTMLElement;
      form: HTMLFormElement;
      h1: HTMLHeadingElement;
      h2: HTMLHeadingElement;
      h3: HTMLHeadingElement;
      h4: HTMLHeadingElement;
      h5: HTMLHeadingElement;
      h6: HTMLHeadingElement;
      head: HTMLHeadElement;
      header: HTMLElement;
      hgroup: HTMLElement;
      hr: HTMLHRElement;
      html: HTMLHtmlElement;
      i: HTMLElement;
      iframe: HTMLIFrameElement;
      img: HTMLImageElement;
      input: HTMLInputElement;
      ins: HTMLModElement;
      kbd: HTMLElement;
      label: HTMLLabelElement;
      legend: HTMLLegendElement;
      li: HTMLLIElement;
      link: HTMLLinkElement;
      main: HTMLElement;
      map: HTMLMapElement;
      mark: HTMLElement;
      menu: HTMLMenuElement;
      meta: HTMLMetaElement;
      meter: HTMLMeterElement;
      nav: HTMLElement;
      noscript: HTMLElement;
      object: HTMLObjectElement;
      ol: HTMLOListElement;
      optgroup: HTMLOptGroupElement;
      option: HTMLOptionElement;
      output: HTMLOutputElement;
      p: HTMLParagraphElement;
      picture: HTMLPictureElement;
      pre: HTMLPreElement;
      progress: HTMLProgressElement;
      q: HTMLQuoteElement;
      rp: HTMLElement;
      rt: HTMLElement;
      ruby: HTMLElement;
      s: HTMLElement;
      samp: HTMLElement;
      script: HTMLScriptElement;
      section: HTMLElement;
      select: HTMLSelectElement;
      slot: HTMLSlotElement;
      small: HTMLElement;
      source: HTMLSourceElement;
      span: HTMLSpanElement;
      strong: HTMLElement;
      style: HTMLStyleElement;
      sub: HTMLElement;
      summary: HTMLElement;
      sup: HTMLElement;
      table: HTMLTableElement;
      tbody: HTMLTableSectionElement;
      td: HTMLTableCellElement;
      template: HTMLTemplateElement;
      textarea: HTMLTextAreaElement;
      tfoot: HTMLTableSectionElement;
      th: HTMLTableCellElement;
      thead: HTMLTableSectionElement;
      time: HTMLTimeElement;
      title: HTMLTitleElement;
      tr: HTMLTableRowElement;
      track: HTMLTrackElement;
      u: HTMLElement;
      ul: HTMLUListElement;
      var: HTMLElement;
      video: HTMLVideoElement;
      wbr: HTMLElement;
    } => ({ ...props });
```

Lastly, you can make a `createAllTheElements` reusable function with this type by doing

```
    export const createAllTheElements = (
      props: keyof DocumentCreateElementTagNameTandem
    ):
      | HTMLElement
      | HTMLObjectElement
      | HTMLMapElement
      | HTMLLinkElement
      | HTMLAnchorElement
      | HTMLAreaElement
      | HTMLAudioElement
      | HTMLBaseElement
      | HTMLQuoteElement
      | HTMLBodyElement
      | HTMLBRElement
      | HTMLButtonElement
      | HTMLCanvasElement
      | HTMLTableCaptionElement
      | HTMLTableColElement
      | HTMLDataElement
      | HTMLDataListElement
      | HTMLModElement
      | HTMLDetailsElement
      | HTMLDialogElement
      | HTMLDivElement
      | HTMLDListElement
      | HTMLEmbedElement
      | HTMLFieldSetElement
      | HTMLFormElement
      | HTMLHeadingElement
      | HTMLHeadElement
      | HTMLHRElement
      | HTMLHtmlElement
      | HTMLIFrameElement
      | HTMLImageElement
      | HTMLInputElement
      | HTMLLabelElement
      | HTMLLegendElement
      | HTMLLIElement
      | HTMLMenuElement
      | HTMLMetaElement
      | HTMLMeterElement
      | HTMLOListElement
      | HTMLOptGroupElement
      | HTMLOptionElement
      | HTMLOutputElement
      | HTMLParagraphElement
      | HTMLPictureElement
      | HTMLPreElement
      | HTMLProgressElement
      | HTMLSlotElement
      | HTMLScriptElement
      | HTMLSelectElement
      | HTMLSourceElement
      | HTMLSpanElement
      | HTMLStyleElement
      | HTMLTableElement
      | HTMLTemplateElement
      | HTMLTableSectionElement
      | HTMLTableCellElement
      | HTMLTextAreaElement
      | HTMLTimeElement
      | HTMLTitleElement
      | HTMLTableRowElement
      | HTMLTrackElement
      | HTMLUListElement
      | HTMLVideoElement => document.createElement(props);
```

Comment: To avoid this extra login I am rendering a component, it should do the trick I have missed creating the element. Your suggestion seem too complex for me. Thanks for your time!